# ViewModel-based validation with Angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvvm, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to have a JavaScript view model object that contains validation rules, similar to ASP.NET MVC view models with data annotations, that I can bind to Angular views. Then, I would e.g. like to call a `Validate` method on that object at certain stages in its lifetime before posting it to a server.

This would allow for me to stay close to an MVVM-like approach, where the UI is quite light and not sooo smart, and the view model, whatever view model, that is represented by a view, need to require changes to the view markup in order to change validation rules.

This way I can even possibly leverage MVC's data annotations to build a serializable view model, with rules, on the server, and return that model and all it's validations etc. to the client as JSON.

How could I go about achieving this type of validation in Angular, vs. the much more common, per element/model property validation achieved by means of directives?

Comment: I would love to hear an answer for this as I am beginning a project with nearly this exact set up!

Comment: what are you using for your model? PetaPoco, entity framework etc.  I have added validation to the object classes in the past by creating partial classes that extend the base object class of the model.  I can then call a validate method of the class and it returns erros (i used this approach in a WPF application) but I am not sure how to serialize this into an angluar app.  Might have to be another service that the view model consumes and then parses the required objects.

Comment: I'm using good old POCOs, but with data annotations attributes on the model properties for validation rules. MVC already has such a service, as it adds ModelMetadata to the ViewPage. In the page, I can use ng-init to pass this to the model, but that feels quite clumsy.

Comment: You could transform the imperative validation logic to be contained in the JSON model itself - http://martinfowler.com/articles/refactoring-adaptive-model.html.  This is basically turning your JSON into a DSL of sorts that can be shared between the server and the client.

Comment: @FrailWords That is exactly what I want to do, i.e. include the metadata in the JSON, but my question is more on how to implement this, and the resultant validation, in Angular. So many people preach to always use directives for validation, but then the view is implementing business rules, not the view model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have implemented something that might help you on the most recent project I am working on. We use AngularJS on the front-end and ASP.NET WEB API on the back-end. All of the HTML forms are generated automatically based on the properties and data annotations contained in my POCO classes.

On the server-side I have entities and DTO's. My entities contain the database specific annotations and DTO's contain my view specific annotations. I will give a brief example showing one property in one class and how I render the UI for this. Here are the server-side objects:

```
public class Discount
{
    [StringLength(40)]
    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; } 
}

public class DiscountDto : IDto<Discount>
{
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(ApplicationStrings), Name = "Name", ShortName = "Name_Placeholder")]
    [UI(Row = 1, Width = 6)]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

This property gets rendered on the UI like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Name: </label> 
  <div class="col-sm-6"> 
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="model[options.key]"  required="required" maxlength="40" placeholder="Enter the name...">
  </div>
</div>
```

The `<input />` field has the `required`, `placeholder` and `maxlength` properties auto set. The HTML label, bootstrap column widths are also auto set based on the custom `UI` data annotation. Row = 1 means to to display this field first in the form and Width = 6 means the field should take up a column width of 6: `class="col-sm-6"`. The label text and placeholder text are pulled from Resource files.
If this is what you are looking for then read on :-)

I have created a Controller `MetaController` that takes in the name of the DTO as a parameter: `api/Meta/DiscountDTO` for example. This controller simply loops through all the properties on the DTO object and the associated entity and pulls out the data annotations, transforms them into a `FormMetadata` class and returns a `List<FormMetadata>` to the client. The `FormMetadata` class just contains properties like `IsRequired`, `IsDisplayed`, `IsReadonly`, etc. just to turn the annotations into something more readable for the front-end developers. Here is a snippet from the MetaController:

```
var type = Type.GetType("<DTO_goes_here>");
List<FormMetadata> formMetadata = new List<FormMetadata>();

foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
{
    var metadata = new FormMetadata();
    metadata.Key = prop.Name.ToLower().Substring(0, 1) + prop.Name.Substring(1, prop.Name.Length - 1);
    metadata.Type = prop.PropertyType.FullName;

    object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);

    foreach (Attribute attr in attrs)
    {
        if (attr is RequiredAttribute)
        {
            metadata.IsRequired = true;
        }
        else if (attr is StringLengthAttribute)
        {
            var sla = (attr as StringLengthAttribute);
            metadata.MinLength = sla.MinimumLength; 
            metadata.MaxLength = sla.MaximumLength;
        }
        // etc.
    }

    formMetadata.Add(metadata);
}
```

This endpoint would return the following JSON for the Name property:

```
{  
   "$id":"3",
   "key":"name",
   "display":"Name",
   "type":"System.String",
   "placeholder":"Enter the name...",
   "isRequired":true,
   "isEditable":true,
   "isDisplayed":true,
   "isReadonly":false,
   "displayInList":true,
   "width":6,
   "row":1,
   "col":0,
   "order":0,
   "maxLength":40,
   "minLength":0,
   "lookup":null,
   "displayAs":null
}
```

On the client side I have created a custom Angular directive `<entity-form />` that takes in the name of the DTO as a parameter like so:

`<entity-form entity-type="DiscountDTO"></entity-form>`. This directive will then call the `MetaController` to get the validation rules for the `Discount` entity and render the form based on the rules returned. To render the form I use an awesome library called [angular-formly](http://angular-formly.com/#/). This library allows to create forms from javascript without writing any HTML. I won't get in to too much detail about angular-formly here but you basically create a Javascript object with the details of the form you want to render and pass it into an angular-formly directive and it takes care of rendering the form for you. This is a basic example of the type of object you pass to angular-formly to render an `<input />` box with a label of "Text":

```
{
  "key": "text",
  "type": "input",
  "templateOptions": {
    "label": "Text",
    "placeholder": "Type here to see the other field become enabled..."
  }
}
```

So, I basically take the metadata returned from the `MetaController` and build up an object that angular-formly understands and pass it into the angular-formly directive and it renders the form for me. I know this answer could have been a LOT longer with more examples, etc. but I felt this was a lot to read through as is. I hope this gives you enough info.

I would love to make this more generic and open-source it - if anyone is interested in working on something like this let me know :-)

Comment: I like what you've done here. Not quite what I'm looking for, but quite enlightening.

Comment: Very neat -  exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

According to [MVC and MVVM with AngularJS](http://codechutney.in/blog/javascript/mvc-and-mvvm-with-angularjs/), AngularJS follows **MVVM** design pattern.

I think you need something like [Adding Unobtrusive Client Validation from the Microsoft .NET MVC Framework to Angular](https://github.com/mdekrey/unobtrusive-angular-validation).

If you wanna create **custom HTML helper** for Razor, See [Validation in Angular forms](http://dotnetspeak.com/2013/11/validation-in-angular-forms-part-2) which has 2 parts.

I also found [ngval](https://github.com/alisabzevari/ngval) which seems *not to be stable*.

Comment: I can't agree with your first link, where the author calls the controller the View Model and basically calls `$scope` the Model. No, I strongly disagree that Angular is MVVM, but rather MVC, where Model in the Angular context should read equivalent to View Model, the other (real) model being the server side domain model.

The other links seem very interesting, and useful, though, thanks.

Comment: @ProfK My understanding of MVVM is like yours and I agree with you, but I thought the link could be useful :)